# Docker Apache HTTP/2 Warning -- [http2:warn] [pid 1] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2

Tags: docker, apache, http2

Using Docker, I'm building an Apache server that supports HTTP/2 communication.
However, it is not compatible with HTTP/2 due to the module.

[Warning Message]\

```
[http2:warn] [pid 1] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
```

[Environment Version]
macOS: Monterey v12.4 
Server version: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) 
Docker version: 23.0.5

I wrote the following in my Dockerfile for a solution, and commented out the LoadModule in the actual environment configuration file, but it doesn't seem to work.

-Dockerfile

```
RUN sed -i \
        -e 's/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_mpm_event.so\)/\1/' \
        -e '/mod_mpm_prefork.so/s/^/#/' \
        /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

Comment: The error seems quite clear. Either don't use the prefork mpm or don't use HTTP2.